Integrating Video on image target on Unity 2022
I am using Unity version 2022.3.21f1 With the Vuforia package Version'10', I am integrating a video on a real image within the scope of Augmented Reality. For this, I create a plane on the image target(which is a cloud reco) in Hierarchy and assign a video to the inspector window. However, when I test, the video does not show on the real image target : it starts on the image target which is the video player assigned to not to the real image target ,it's really confused thing and image target(which is in Hierarchy ) when testing it moves around not fixed at one position : the position & rotation values are changes at the meantime.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/GPYYRdUQ.png)
I am trying to scan an image target & get a video on it.
What O get is that the video is not shown on the image target as expected.
NB: I was using Unity2019 & Vuforia8, and it was working fine, but after upgrading to Unity 2022, the problem showed up.

have you looked at this migration guide? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/project-migration/how-migrate-unity-project

i had upgraded my scripts to what fits vuforia 10

Hi @LivePrint, have you checked the ImageTargets scene in the Vuforia Core Samples? https://u3d.as/Wfq
The scene contains an example of a VideoPlayer used with the "Fissure" ImageTarget.
Also, could you please clarify what you mean with: "it starts on the image target which is the video player assigned to not to the real image target"?

Hi @ptc-epassaro i will check the link you send me thank you.
About clarifying whay i meant is : in the scene the video player is a child of the image target. the real image target is when i test the app so i meant with that a busniss card or what i am going to use i hope i make it clear for you now

https://www.reddit.com/user/Civil-Spot-8378/comments/1ffxj22/video_is_not_appearing_on_image_target_as_expected/
if you can check this link you will find a video about the values of te image target position & rotation when i start testing

The ImageTarget moves because the World Center Mode on the VuforiaBehaviour is probably set to DEVICE. Which means that the camera is a the origin and all the targets are positioned relative to it. So the GameObject follows the movement of the target relative to the camera of your device. If you want the target to stay still and the camera to move, try to set the World Center Mode to FIRST_TARGET.

FIRST_TARGET only makes it stable but does not solve the problem which is the video does not appear on the image target as normally should

Could you please create a bug report here? https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues
If possible, it would be very helpful if you could specify the exact version of Vuforia you're using and also attach a video of the issue you are seeing. Thank you!

Yeah of course if that may help solving the problem
